# How can I take variables from @Route? Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My problem is:

I want take two variables from @route like this:

```
class MultimediaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @Route("/{sku}/{dimension}")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function indexAction($sku, $dimension)
    {
        $sku = {sku};

        return $this->render('ExampleFrontMultimediaBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Please read the documentation before ask here.

Comment: $sku already available in your controller but parameter name should be same as router tokens, `s` is missing in your indexAction parameter for $dimension.

Comment: @Mattia Lol sorry I am really new with symfony and I dont know how to search good in their document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `$sku`.

If the parameter is defined in the route declaration and passed as argument to the function, the argument (i.e. `$sku`) will take the value of the route parameter.

So if you browse `/test/123`, `$sku` will be equal to `"test"` and `$dimension` will be equal to `123`.

This is the first paragraph of the [Routing documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-in-action).

Comment: Alternatively you inject the request object using `public function indexAction(Request $request)` and then get the parameters using `$sku = $request->get('sku');`.

Comment: @qooplmao This is mandatory if the parameter isn't passed as argument, or if the parameter is not explicitly defined in the route definition, but in this case ùi think that inject the whole Request object rather than the parameter is a bit overkill.

Comment: Oh yeah, probably. Just saying that it is a possibility, that's why I just added as a comment rather than an attempt at an answer.